# Entering URL in browser causes Python Django ReverseMatchError to be thrown

Tags: python, html, django

I am working on a Python project while following a book to create an online shop website, I have created the `models`, `views` and `urls` for the app named `'Shop'` the project overall is called `'My shop'`. Whenever I try to type in the `'product list'` URL I am returned with the following error:

`Reverse for 'product_list_by_category' with arguments '(3, 'accessories')' not found.`

The expected result is the `list.html` page to be shown which includes all products because no category has been chosen in the URL.

I have followed the code in the book exactly and have tried it multiple times yet the error still appears.
I have two categories currently and two games, the games are Minecraft and GTA 5, the categories are Accessories and Games.

Below is the code from all of the relevant files, if any more are needed let me know.

Shop `views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Category, Product

# Create your views here.

#Product List view
def product_list(request, category_slug=None):
    #Setting current category to none
    category = None
    #Retrieiving categories
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    #Getting all unfiltered products that are available
    products = Product.objects.filter(available=True)
    #Filtering products based on category
    if category_slug:
        #Get category
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
        #Get products from category
        products = products.filter(category=category)
    #Return view with context (Product and category)
    return render(request, 
        'shop/product/list.html', 
        {'category': category,
         'categories': categories,
         'products': products})

#Individual product view
def product_detail(request, id, slug):
    #Return product
    product = get_object_or_404(Product,
                                id=id,
                                slug=slug,
                                available=True)
    #Return view with context (Product)
    return render(request, 
        'shop/product/detail.html',
        {'product': product})
```

Shop `urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

#Create URLS here

app_name = 'shop'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.product_list, name='product_list'),
    path('<slug:category_slug>/', views.product_list, name='product_list_by_category'),
    path('<int:id>/<slug:slug>/', views.product_detail, name='product_detail'),

]
```

Shop `models.py`

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
# Create your models here.

#Create catalog model
class Category(models.Model):
    #Name of category
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    #Slug Name (Link)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    #Meta data
    class Meta:
        #Alphabetical ordering by category name
        ordering = ('name',)
        #Name for one category
        verbose_name = 'category'
        #Name for multiple categories
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'
    #Returning the name
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        #Return reverse of product
        return reverse('shop:product_list_by_category', args=[self.id, self.slug])
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

#Create Product Model
class Product(models.Model):
    #Create relation (Foreign Key) to Category model
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='products', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    """
    db_index ensures that name and slug are used as a COMPOSITE PRIMARY key
    Name of product
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    #Slug Name (Link)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    #Product image (Saved in static image folder)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)
    #Description of product
    description = models.TextField()
    #Price of product
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    #Product availability
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    #Product Creation date
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    #Product last updated
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    #Meta data
    class Meta:
        #Order alphabetically by name
        ordering = ('name',)
        #Product index is created with id and slug
        index_together = (('id', 'slug'),)
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        #Return reverse of product
        return reverse('shop:product_detail', args=[self.id, self.slug])
    #Returning product name
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Project `urls.py`

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
"""MyShop URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('shop.urls', namespace='shop')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I have three HTML pages: `List`, `Detail` and `Base`

`list.html`

```
<!--Loading content from base.html and loading static files-->
{% extends "shop/base.html" %}
{% load static %}

<!--Title block-->
{% block title %}
    {% if category %}{{ category.name }}{% else %}Products{% endif %}
{% endblock %}

<!--Content block (Main stuff)-->
{% block content %}
<div id="sidebar">
    <h3>Categories</h3>
    <ul>
        <li {% if not category%}class="selected" {% endif %}>
            <a href='{% url "shop:product_list" %}'>All</a>
        </li>
        {% for c in categories %}
            <li {% if category.slug == c.slug %} class="selected"{% endif %}>
                <a href="{{ c.get_absolute_url }}">{{ c.name }}</a>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="main" class="product-list">
    <h1>{% if category %}{{ category.name }}{% else %}Products{% endif %}</h1>
    {% for product in products %}
        <div class="item">
            <a href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}">
                <img src='{% if product.image %}{{ product.image.url }}{% else %}{% static "img/no_image.png" %}{% endif %}'/>
            </a>
            <a href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}">{{ product.name }}</a>
            <br>
            £{{ product.price }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

`detail.html` currently has no code and `base.html` is definitely not the cause.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Showing the full debug page that showing the error would be more helpful, can you please include it ?

Answer (score 0):

Your get absolute url in the `Category` model is calling the `product_list_by_category` url only which only accepts one arg(parameter).
You can change

```
path('<slug:category_slug>/', views.product_list, name='product_list_by_category')
```

to

```
path('<int:id>/<slug:category_slug>/', views.product_list, name='product_list_by_category')
```